# How do I make a TLight show in Delphi FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to make a 3D application where a `TLight` casts light  in a 3D cube, but I found no way to "enable" the light and it does nothing.

Comment: Add firemonkey to your question's tags. Also, include some example code.

Comment: @XylemFlow there is no code. I have no Idea how the `TLight` component works

Comment: Your cube needs to have a TLightMaterial. Start on doing this by adding a [TLightMaterialSource](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.MaterialSources.TLightMaterialSource) component to your form.

Comment: @Brian I did that. And it still does not work

Comment: Did you assign the TLightMaterialSource source as the source of the materialsource of the cube? Might also be easier to make your light a point source and move it around vs the default directional which if it points away from the cube won't do much.

Comment: Add a TViewport3D, Add a TRectangle3D, Add a TLight, Add a TLightMaterialSource. Now set the properties of the TRectangle3D for MaterialBackSource, MaterialShaftSource and MaterialSource all to the TLightMaterialSource that you added.

Comment: If you right click the tab and click 'View as Form', you can then paste that code into your question. We can then see exactly what you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MaterialSource of your cube needs to be a TLightMaterial. Do that by putting a TLightMaterialSource on your form and hooking it up to the cube. To make it easier to see make the light a point source. Once done and looking similar to the below you can move the lightsource around and see the cube lit differently.

[image]